# Google bookmarks, delicious, and chrome sync

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, firefox, delicious, google-bookmarks

I'm not certain if I should ask this here or on SuperUser. Since Chrome OS is (mostly) all in the cloud, here goes...

I heard this morning that Yahoo is [shutting down delicious](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2010/12/16/delicious.php). (*Edit: This may not be the case.*) I've been using delicious for years to store bookmarks and access them on multiple computers with various browsers and OSes. It makes sense for me to move to Google Bookmarks, but I can't figure out how to get bookmarks into the system, particularly the HTML export file that delicious produces.

How can I import this list in a way that I can access these bookmarks on multiple chrome installations (one on windows, one on chromium) and also from a mac using firefox? **It's important that I keep tags intact**. Google Bookmarks and chrome sync are confusing, and seem to be separate systems. Can they do this?

I'd prefer a system that uses the cloud as much as possible and will let me export bookmarks, since I don't know what systems I'll be using in a year.

If this has been asked, I apologize; I looked through similar questions, and didn't find quite the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Update: Delicious may not be dead after all. See http://blog.delicious.com/blog/2010/12/whats-next-for-delicious.html

Comment: Here's a more direct answer about importing from delicious while keeping tags intact: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/moving-delicious-bookmarks-to-google-bookmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) is excellent. Here is a post discussing how to transfer bookmarks from Delicious to Xmarks: [link](http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=2144)

Comment: I already use xmarks for tab sharing between browsers, and it works very well. I can move from one computer to another and keep the same browsing session going. However, I'd like to keep bookmarks on google bookmarks if it's possible for me to do so.

Comment: Just discovered, xmarks is also [closing down early next year](http://lifehacker.com/5649435/xmarks-bookmark-syncing-shutting-down-in-january-2011). You can keep using it if you can set up your own server.

Comment: nope. xmarks was  purchased/saved by LastPass, which is keeping it alive and improving it