# Moving Delicious bookmarks to Google Bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks, delicious, google-bookmarks

Is it possible to copy all my Delicious bookmarks to Google Bookmarks, while preserving the Delicious tags as Google labels?

It is easy enough to export as HTML and import again, but the tags get lost in the process.

Answer (score 6):

This [link](http://persistent.info/delicious2google/) might help you. It will just ask your Delicious username & password, no harm/no issues as the script available as open source. Just give it a try.

Source: http://blog.persistent.info/2006/10/import-your-delicious-bookmarks-into.html

Answer (score 4):

Google bookmarks now directly [offers the feature](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/deliciousimport) to import bookmarks from Delicious.

A couple things to note:

- If you have thousands of bookmarks, be very patient, as it can take a while.
- I'm not sure if this is an issue when you import now, but when I used this tool several years ago, I found that there were [indexing problems when searching for bookmarks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41325/is-there-a-workaround-for-google-bookmark-search-problems).