# How to migrate del.icio.us bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks, delicious

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving delicious bookmarks to google bookmarks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/moving-delicious-bookmarks-to-google-bookmarks)

I would like to migrate all my bookmarks from del.icio.us to google bookmarks. Are there any tools available to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- [Import del.icio.us Bookmarks into Google Bookmarks](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2006/10/import-delicious-bookmarks-into-google.html)

> Mihai Parparita from Google has
>   written [a(nother) cool script](http://blog.persistent.info/2006/10/import-your-delicious-bookmarks-into.html) that
>   allows you to add the bookmarks from
>   del.ico.us to Google Bookmarks. The
>   live version [is available on his site](http://delicious-export.appspot.com/).
>
> Unlike del.icio.us, Google Bookmarks
>   keeps your favorite web pages private
>   and lets you search their content. You
>   can manage your bookmarks from the
>   site, using Google Toolbar for IE or
>   using some unofficial Firefox
>   extensions.

- http://blog.persistent.info/2006/10/import-your-delicious-bookmarks-into.html
- http://delicious-export.appspot.com/

---

- [An internet search will give you many ideas like that.](http://www.google.com.pk/search?rlz=1C1GGGE_enPK361PK361&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=import+del.icio.us+bookmarks+into+google+bookmarks)