# Importing Del.icio.us to Google Bookmarks

Tags: delicious, google-bookmarks

Delicious used to be amazing, but now sucks. I'm looking for a decent alternative that does

- tag clouds,
- auto-complete on tags
- and generally has the amazing goodness that delicious had in 2009+.

I tried Diigo, but found the interface awkward an non-intuitive. I'm now trying Google Bookmarks, but the "import delicious bookmarks" feature isn't working .

- screen-shot 1 is import failed try via del.icio.us username

[image]

- screen-shot 2 is import failed try via Yahoo OAuth

[image]

Alternatively, Google Bookmarks provides a weird manual import process that forces you to

- download your bookmarks
- import those bookmarks into FF,
- then use FF's Google Toolbar to pass FF Bookmarks to "Google Bookmarks". It's bad enough that the alternative to the broken import function, is forcing me to install Google Toolbar to import some bookmarks. The kicker is that Google Toolbar doesn't work for my version of FF (5+).

I've seen this older post, [Moving delicious bookmarks to Google Bookmarks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/moving-delicious-bookmarks-to-google-bookmarks) , describing the method. But that seems to be the same "not-working-delicious" function that Google Bookmarks started using.

Is there a sane, working way to import delicious bookmarks (with tags), to Google Bookmarks?

Comment: If you used to access delicious through Yahoo, there was a push a while back to convert your Yahoo-based delicious account to a delicious-only one.  Did you transition your account? (Google seems to still want to validate through Yahoo, which I do not think will work)

Comment: @Frye: Have you actually tried the method provided in the other question or are you assuming that it won't work?

Comment: @jonsca I originally started out with a delicious account. They were bought by Yahoo after I had been using it for some time. I tried both the i) Yahoo ID and ii) Delicious ID, to import to Google. None worked.

Comment: @Barry Yes, I tried the online tool given in that post. It didn't work. Got the same -non-working-ness that the Google Bookmarks gave me.

Answer (score 3):

There's an import function at:

https://www.google.com/bookmarks/deliciousimport

It works with the new Delicious and imports tags and everything correctly.

Comment: Right. This is the tool that I mentioned originally. What I did figure out, was that there is an 'import' button that was hidden from my view.

Because that import tool uses special, hard-to-see scrollbars, it took a longer look to realise that I needed to scroll right about 1/3 of a screen to see the button.

I would show an image, but it's not allowed in comments. Hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I used the [Delicious Exporter to Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pngpaohmgmbakgjnkgkldpihdmjokinj) extension.

It basically creates a Delicious folder in your Google Chrome bookmarks with all your tags nested under it. Is not super-usable but the import works like a charm.